# Misconceptions on notations: Differentiating both sides of the equation $dP/dt=2P-0.002P^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The answer states that the rate of growth is $dP/dt=2P-0.002P^2$.
Therefore $d^2P/dt^2=2-0.004P$
But I have some misconceptions on the notations.
In the first derivative, when you do d/dt to both sides, shouldn’t it become $d^2P/dt^2=(2-0.004P)dP/dt$? This make sense to me if I change it to the y’ form, but it’s confusing in this form, can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac {dP}{dt}=2P-0.002P^2$$
You need to differentiate wrt $P$ to get that:
$$\dfrac {dP'}{dP}=2-0.004P$$
Otherwise:
$$\dfrac {d^2P}{dt^2}=(2-0.004P)\dfrac {dP}{dt}$$

Comment: You get the answer of the book @PeterWang if you differentiate wrt to $P$ only

Comment: If you differentiate wrt P, then how did answer of the book get $d^2P/dt^2$ on the left side?

Comment: I don't know. I am just saying that to get the RHS you neeed to differentiate wrt $P$ not $t$. @PeterWang

Comment: Thanks, I just did some more research and got that since $dP/dt$ is a function in terms of P, so you do derivative wrt P. Now I suspect that the book has some issue, but it’s a Barron AP calculus book, so I don’t know...

Answer (score 4):

Your observation is correct.  We have

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(2P-0.002P^2\right)=2\frac{dP}{dt}-0.004P\frac{dP}{dt}$$

Comment: @aryadeva Thank you.  Much appreciated.

Comment: In this case, how do I get the second derivative like the answer did?

Comment: @PeterWang differentiate wrt to P